# Highlight multiple rows using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm putting together a succinct [jQuery matrix](http://www.phillipsenn.com/Index/jQuery/Matrix.htm) because I'm having a hard time navigating around on the jQuery site, and the cheat sheets don't seem to provide me what I want either.

Here's how I highlight the rows:

```
$('.eq').hover(function() {
    $('.eq').toggleClass('highlight');
});
$('.is').hover(function() {
    $('.is').toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Q: How can I write a function that says "toggle everything in the same class as what is being hovered over"?  Something like:

```
function toggle(that){
    $(that.className).toggleClass('highlight');
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you know that [tables can have multiple `tbody` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table)?

Just wrap sets of rows in separate `tbody` elements. And then we can use:

```
$('tbody').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

And in newer browsers, it can be done using CSS only:

```
tbody {
    /* Normal style */
}

tbody:hover {
    /* Highlighted style */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "How can I write a function that says "toggle everything in the same class as what is being hovered over"?"

Elements can have multiple classes, and would you want to do this with *every* element anyway?  A better approach may be to write a plugin for the elements you want, like this:

```
$.fn.highlightClass = function() {
  return this.hover(function() {
    $("."+this.className.split(" ").join(",.")).toggleClass("highlight");
  });
};
```

Then you'd call it on the elements you care about, for example:

```
$(".eq, .is").highlightClass();
```

If you had for example a `class="eq test"` element, it'd change it to a `".eq,.test"` selector, and toggle the `highlight` class on all of those elements.  Just change the `.join()` call to `.join(".")` if you want it to only highlight elements with *all* the classes of the elements you're hovering, as opposed to *any* of the classes...like I have above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are assigning only one class to the HTML element that is hovered then use this slightly  changed version:

```
function toggle(that){
    $("." + that.className).toggleClass('highlight');
}
```