# deleting data from website without refresh

Tags: javascript, html

So I am using firebase to save data for my codes. In my code i have managed to save data in firebase, but what i am trying to do in my code is to delete data in firebase, i made that happend but the innerHTML wont delete immediatly i have to refresh my page to see the data disappear from the webpage, can anyone help me?

before you have a look at my code, my code is basicly about registering something called "Russ" with name, adress, mobilenumber and gender.

hope you guys understand what im doing in the code as its written in Norwegian

Thank you for your help and time

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Russetid</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div>
 <center>
 <h1>Russestyret 2018</h1>
 <form id="registrering">
    <label>Navn: <input id="inpnavn" placeholder="Raahim Khan" type="text" required></label>
    <label>Adresse: <input id="inpadresse" type="text" placeholder="Adresse 12" required></label>
    <label>Mobilnummer: <input id="inpmobilnummer" placeholder="12345678" required></select></label>
    <label>Kjønn: 
      <select id="inpkjønn" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Velg kjønn</option>
        <option>Mann</option>
        <option>Kvinne</option>
        <option>intetkjønn</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Send inn</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<!-- buttons allowing me to see either all the registered russ or only menn, women or neuter -->
<button class="vis" onclick="visAlleruss()">Vis alle</button>
<button class="vis" onclick="visMenn()">Vis Menn</button>
<button class="vis" onclick="visKvinner()">Vis Kvinner</button>
<button class="vis" onclick="visIntetkjønn()">Vis intetkjønn</button>
<table width="500px;">
    <tr><th>Navn</th><th>Adresse</th><th>Mobilnummer</th><th>Kjønn</th><th>Slett:</th></tr>
    <tbody id="txttabell"></tbody>
</table>
```

```
<script>
    var inpnavn = document.getElementById("inpnavn");
    var inpadresse =  document.getElementById("inpadresse");
    var inpmobilnummer = document.getElementById("inpmobilnummer");
    var inpkjønn = document.getElementById("inpkjønn");
    var registrering = document.getElementById("registrering");
    var txttabell = document.getElementById("txttabell");

    var database = firebase.database();
    var russ = database.ref();


    //delete function
    function slett(pk) {
        var slettruss = russ.child(pk);
        slettruss.remove();
        var div = document.getElementById(pk);
        txttabell.removeChild(div);
    }


    //register function
    function registrereruss(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var navn = inpnavn.value;
        var adresse = inpadresse.value;
        var mobilnummer = inpmobilnummer.value;
        var kjønn = inpkjønn.value;


        inpnavn.value = "";
        inpadresse.value = "";
        inpmobilnummer.value = "";
        inpkjønn.value = "";


        russ.push({
            "navn" : navn,
            "adresse" : adresse,
            "mobilnummer" : mobilnummer,
            "kjønn" : kjønn

        });

    }

    //showing the data on website
    function hentruss(snapshot){
        var pk = snapshot.key;
        var nyruss = snapshot.val();
        var russref = database.ref("russ/" + nyruss.russ);
        russref.on("value", function(snapshotruss){
            var russobj = snapshotruss.val();
            txttabell.innerHTML += `
            <div id="${pk}">
            <tr><td>${nyruss.navn}</td><td>${nyruss.adresse}</td><td>${nyruss.mobilnummer}</td><td>${nyruss.kjønn}</td><td><label class="delete" onclick="slett('${pk}')">X</label></td></tr>
            </div>
            `;

        });
    }
    //functions for the buttons
    function visAlleruss(){
      txttabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .on("child_added", hentruss);    
}

    function visMenn(){
      txttabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .orderByChild("kjønn")
      .equalTo("Mann")
      .on("child_added", hentruss);    
}


    function visKvinner(){
      txttabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .orderByChild("kjønn")
      .equalTo("Kvinne")
      .on("child_added", hentruss);    
}

    function visIntetkjønn(){
      txttabell.innerHTML = "";
      russ
      .orderByChild("kjønn")
      .equalTo("intetkjønn")
      .on("child_added", hentruss);    
}


    registrering.onsubmit = registrereruss;
    russ.on("child_added", hentruss);
</script>
```

Comment: after delete function completed hide data in html DOM

Comment: isnt that what i did in var div = document.getElementById(pk);
        txttabell.removeChild(div);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping `<tr>` in `<div>` is a really bad idea, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258202/is-it-really-bad-idea-to-group-tr-tags-with-div).
Some web browsers will re-arrange the DOM objects, which will break the logic in function `slett`.

Please remove the `<div>` wrapper. See if moving the `id` to the `<tr>` tag works for you.

```
txttabell.innerHTML += `
<tr id="${pk}"><td>${nyruss.navn}</td><td>${nyruss.adresse}</td><td>${nyruss.mobilnummer}</td><td>${nyruss.kjønn}</td><td><label class="delete" onclick="slett('${pk}')">X</label></td></tr>
`;
```

Comment: thank you very much, this helped me with not only delete problem but i now know how to make a valid edit function, i just have one problem with the edit function and was wondering if you could help me with that aswell. il make a new thread to for that problem, but again thanks :)