# Grouping table rows and page breaks

Tags: css

I have a relatively long table.  Each record has six rows.  So an item with an identifier of 16 has `<tr-16-1><tr-16-2>.....<tr-16-6>`, identifier 25 would be `<tr-25-1><tr-25-2>.....<tr-25-6>`, etc.

I would like the page breaks to not split any grouping of the six rows.  So if `<tr-25-6>` would continue on a new page, I would like all `<tr-25's>` to break with it.

I can easily attach a class to all six rows if that would help.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to do this?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: when say _on a new page_ are you talking about print rules?

Answer (score 5):

A possibility is grouping all the rows that are referring to the same record inside a single `tbody`, so you have more `tbody` each one containing 6 rows ([it's perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table) and seems to be logical as an atomic group),
then add this rule for media print

```
@media print {
    tbody {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

In this way a page break inside a `tbody` will be avoided.
Unfortunately `page-break-inside` is supported on every modern browser [except Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/page-break-inside#section_5) (Bug [#132035](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132035))

Comment: Just gave that a try - wrapped all the tr groups in their own tbody tags but, unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem.  I tried in both Chrome and IE.

Comment: could you post an example fiddle with some data and update your question? I'll try to investigate further

Comment: Thanks so much.  I posted a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/wKvuP/.  You may need to repeat the data in order to create enough info for a page break.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would give this a shot:

```
@media print {
    tr, td, th { page-break-inside:avoid }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the @media tag, this is another way:

Add `class=print-entire` to your table, and add this style:

```
table.print-entire tr td, table.print-entire tr th {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
```