# Conditionally adding elements in ng-repeat block

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add stuff to the markup based on condition?
Like in this example, when I want to add `td` only on the first iteration (only for the first element of `myData`)?

```
<tr ng-repeat="m in myData">
   <td>{{m.Name}}</td>
   <td>{{m.LastName}}</td>

   @if myData.indexOf(m) = 0 then // something like that
   <td rowspan ="{{m.length}}">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="d in days">
           {{d.hours}}
        </li>
      </ul>
   </td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, AngularJS has 2 directives for this occasion:

- The [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)  / [ng-hide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) family of directives can be used to hide (by
  using display CSS rules) parts of the DOM three based on a result of
  evaluating an expression.
- If we want to physically remove / add parts of the DOM conditionally
  the family of [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) directives (ng-switch, ng-switch-when,
  ng-switch-default) will come handy.

At the end of the day both solutions will give the same visual effect but the underlying DOM structure will be different. For simple use cases ng-show / ng-hide is probably OK, but larger portions of the DOM should be treated with ng-switch.

For the use case from this question I would advice using ng-switch.

Comment: Just to add. $index have the current index of the item, so ng-show="$index == 0"

Comment: As of Angular 1.1.5, you can also use `ng-if="your expression"` directive. You add it as an attribute to any element. If it validates to true, it adds that element to the dom.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution should be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="m in myData">
   <td>{{m.Name}}</td>
   <td>{{m.LastName}}</td>

   <td ng-if="$first" rowspan="{{myData.length}}">
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="d in days">
               {{d.hours}}
           </li>
       </ul>
   </td> 
</tr>
```