# How can I get a bleeding edge version of angular.js from Github?

Tags: angularjs, github

Obviously I can clone the repository, but that's not what I'm after...

If you visit angularjs.org they offer a stable and unstable download of a single, final angular.js file but if you clone the repository you get a whole folder structure (which isn't useful to me).

My question is – how do I get the latest code from Github into this single-file (i.e. angular.min.js) format?

The github repository in question is: https://github.com/angular/angular.js

Comment: [you build it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js#building-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is already described in the README:

```
grunt package
```

Although if you need more detailed descriptions on how to build it, the [official documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute) offers a more comprehensive guide that also explains the dependencies.