# AngularJS: ng-repeat for 2 x <tr> - can't use a DIV

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having an issue i need to repeat the following.. as a group

```
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
```

I can't surround them with a DIV on put the ng-repeat on there as its invalid for TR i.e.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</div>
```

so i currently have the following implemented

```
    <tr ng-repeat.....></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat.....></tr>
```

but the problem is with this there is a collection of 6 items so the first TR renders 6 times and then 6 times for next ...

I am scratching my head trying to get around this but I just can't figure it out.

It would be nice if there was some sort of Div tag that was used for ng-repeat but didn't render an element to the DOM ??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put the ng-repeat on a tbody element :

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.row_one_stuff}}</td>
        <td>{{item.more_row_one_stuff}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.row_two_stuff}}</td>
        <td>{{item.more_row_two_stuff}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Nice -- I forgot you can have multiple tbody elements.

Comment: that works, but it's not so nice if your <tbody> and <tr> have different CSS rules (like in bootstrap).

Answer (score 29):

It looks like the angularjs guys have implemented something along these lines.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2

So the syntax would be

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items"></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

Comment: There's a discussion about the version of angularjs you need here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900050/angular-js-ng-repeat-across-multiple-elements.  Apologies if you end up having to click through a few links, but this will definitely be implemented in a future version.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will keep my eye open for that.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me to repeat 2 distinct <td>'s within a row.

Comment: This solution is more elegant since it is supported officially by `AngularJS` and is more meaningful. This should be the right answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
    <td>{{item.data1}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
    <td>{{item.data2}}</td>
</tr>
```