# ASP.Net MVC page refresh using json values instead of html

Tags: json, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page that has a "prev" and "next" day button, and rather than reload the entire page, I simply do an ajax call to a controller that returns the entire partial view, which I replace the div with.

```
$("#divId").html(ajaxResponse);
```

Pretty simple.

However, I'm finding that this partial view is vastly more data than I need (html doesn't change at all, just the data) and it's causing slowness on mobile browsers.

My question is, is there a tool out there that will let me return a JSON representation of the model data and refresh all the values on the page automatically?

For example, say I have:

```
@Html.InputFor(x => x.FirstName)
```

and the JSON returns

```
{ FirstName: 'Henry', LastName: 'McLeery' }
```

Is there a library available that can automate the process of doing:

```
$("#FirstName").val(ajaxResponse.FirstName);
$("#LastName").val(ajaxResponse.LastName);
etc...
```

?

Comment: You already answer your question, last code. You need to wrap it into $ajax success: function(ajaxResponse) { your code }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/). Angular is a JavaScript framework which uses the mvc pattern.
After binding UI elements to your model the displayed data changes automatically when updating your model. Angular offers a nice api to consume ajax requests with json data.

Look at this:
[Get and update json using angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968099/get-and-update-json-using-angular-js)