# How can I use Angular $http.post() to update a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

For now, all I'm trying to do is read in a simple JSON file, allow the user to edit the contents, and then save it back to the same file. I've read several answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload/14868725), but I'm not dealing with form data or trying to cut out jquery and my understanding (probably the issue) is that it shouldn't be that complicated.

Working off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19969705/5071387) answer, here's what I've got:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as items">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items.testData">
            <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
            <td><input ng-model="item"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="items.update()">Submit</button>
    <p>{{items.msg}}</p>
</div>
```

In the app.js:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", ["$http", function($http) {
    var list = this;
    this.testData = [];
    $http.get("test.json").success(function(data) {
        list.testData = data);
    });
    this.msg = "";

    this.update = function() {
        $http.post("test.json", list.testData);
        this.msg = "saved:" + JSON.stringify(list.testData);
    };
}]);
})();
```

And finally the JSON, just so you see what I see:

```
[
"first item",
"second item",
"3rd item",
"And fourth"
]
```

I'm only working locally right now, so there shouldn't be any issue with my server failing to understand the output (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data?lq=1)). I'm just going JSON to JSON.

Now, my observations-

1. (most importantly) *test.json* never changes when I update(), maybe because
2. testData doesn't seem to actually change, according to the output in msg. Is something wrong with my ng-model? It works in the [above example](http://jsbin.com/EvOSAqo/1/edit?html,css,js,output).
3. There's no error for trying to post to *test.json*, but if I instead set the destination as *test-new.json*, I get **Access to restricted URI denied**. Can I not actually write to a local file at all?

Hopefully, I'm right that this deserved its own question; nothing else I looked at seemed to answer just the basic problems I'm having. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: To actually do something with the data serverside you need to have some serverside code that stores it somewhere, like in a database.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. You can't just write to a local file. You need server side code to do that. It is pretty simple though. You might want to look into json-server (https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

Comment: i think @o4ohel comment would _be_ the accepted answer.