# nested ngRepeat without a wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a JS object like this:

```
[
{
    selected: true,
    itens: [1, 2, 3]
},
{
    selected: true,
    itens: [4, 5, 6]
},
{
    selected: true,
    itens: [7, 8, 9]
},
{
    selected: true,
    itens: [10, 11, 12]
}
]
```

It is a list of objects that have sublists. (this is just a simplified form of my real structure)

I would like to print many divs, one for each sublist item. It would be like this:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>...</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
```

But i do not want wrap the parent items in a external div or another element.
And i also would like to hide the subitems of parents with 'selected' attribute false.

How can i do this with angular ngRepeat directive?

**UPDATE**
I'm trying to list the elements with bootstrap 'row' and 'col' classes. each column is 4 bootstrap columns wide.

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

this is from boostrap documentation.

The resoult should be like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div col-md-4>1</div>
    <div col-md-4>2</div>
    <div col-md-4>3</div>
    <div col-md-4>...</div>
    <div col-md-4>11</div>
    <div col-md-4>12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "object" you posted is actually an array of objects. Both objects and arrays can be ng-repeated over, but with different syntax. To avoid nested objects, you'll probably want to use nested ng-repeat-start directives, like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900050/angular-js-ng-repeat-across-multiple-elements. I'll post an answer once I have time to make one.

Comment: these `<div>` elements will ALWAYS be wrapped in another element, even if that element is the `<body>` element.  Perhaps you can explain a bit more about why another "wrapper" would be a problem?

Comment: you can write filter for extracting properties - so you will end with something like <div ng-repeat="obj in objects | filter:{selected:true} | property:'items'", where property is your custom filter.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I did somewhat similar what you said..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module, you can do that without transforming the model :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayItems | where: {selected: true} | map: 'subitems' | flatten">
    {{item}        
</div>
```

**Explanation :**

- `item in arrayItems` : We are iterating over the *parent* array of items
- `where: {selected: true}` : We keep only those with flag `selected` equals to true
- `map: 'subitems'` : We pluck the property `subitems` (the sub-arrays)
- `flatten` : We flatten the sub-arrays into one array

**See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/035vzqwa/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

It can be possible using ng-repeat itself, only you need to maintain one variable controller.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-init="selectedIndex=0">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected; $parent.selectedIndex=$index">Item {{$index}}</div>
   <div ng-repeat="item in items[selectedIndex].itens" ng-bind="item"></div>
</body>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NKSQ6uTCDwwH0LwNj8xK?p=preview) Here

**Update:**

We need to make one filter that will manage & create selected values `itens` array

**Filter**

```
app.filter('showselected',function($filter){
  return function(values){

    var selectedValues = $filter('filter')(values, {selected: true}), returnValue = [];
    console.log(selectedValues)
    angular.forEach(selectedValues, function(val, index){
      angular.forEach(val.itens, function(v, i){
        returnValue.push(v);
      });
    });
    return returnValue;
  }
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected; $parent.selectedIndex=$index" ng-class="{green: item.selected}">Item {{$index}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items| showselected track by $index" ng-bind="item"></div>
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4NAkXZ3sUlqC3h1B8VN?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get you. In your example is it possible to show just one sublist at a time?
I should see all subitems of selected parents. So, if i have the first and second parent items selected, i should see the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. If i deselect the second one and select the last one, then i would see 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12.

Comment: @Callebe check my updated answer, which is like exactly what you want with select & deselect functionality, Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for voteup..what do you think about my answer. Is it good way or bad?

Comment: It is a pretty good answer. If i could accept tow answers, i would accept yours too. It help me to understand more about filters.
Thank you so much again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73275/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-callebe).

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` doesn't do this sort of thing out of the box.  You'll need to combine all your items arrays into one array that you can iterate over:

```
var arr = [];
test.forEach(function (obj) {
    arr = arr.concat(obj.itens);
});
```

Then, you can use the master array in ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in arr">{{val}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was trying avoid this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsclaus/m3vh0yyc/1/

Results in exactly 12 divs being the only children of the controller element.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: object in array --><!-- ngIf: false -->
<!-- ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    1
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    2
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    3
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><!-- end ngRepeat: object in array --><!-- ngIf: false -->
<!-- ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    4
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    5
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    6
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><!-- end ngRepeat: object in array --><!-- ngIf: false -->
<!-- ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    7
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    8
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    9
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><!-- end ngRepeat: object in array --><!-- ngIf: false -->
<!-- ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    10
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    11
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><div ng-repeat="number in object.itens" ng-repeat-end="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
    12
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: number in object.itens --><!-- end ngRepeat: object in array -->
```