# Chain angularjs repeat in

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to repeat rows in a table based on the amount of data some level deep in an object (more than two)?

Something like:

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="(key2, values) in list where list in (key1, list) in mydata">
      <td rowspan="6" ng-if="$parent.$first">{{key1}}</td>
      <td rowspan="3" ng-if="$first">{{key2}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="value in values">{{value}}</td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

where

```
var mydata = {
   "Subtitle1": {
      "Thing1": { "Value1": 12, "Value2": 43, "Value3": 12 },
      "Thing2": { "Value1": 12, "Value2": 43, "Value3": 12 }
   },
   "Subtitle2": {
      "Thing1": { "Value1": 12, "Value2": 43, "Value3": 12 },
      "Thing2": { "Value1": 12, "Value2": 43, "Value3": 12 }
   }
}
```

I have found a way that works with two levels using the `<tbody>` tag to repeat on the first level and `<tr>` for the second level, but this only works for two levels of data.  What if I have 5 levels?

Similar to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699153, but I want to compact the data to two rows rather than dedicating an entire row (that is mostly empty) for keys.  In that example, **title** and **subtitle** would `rowspan` over **col1** and **col2** ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Rov.png)).

Comment: I can't seem to answer my own question, but I figured out that I can just collapse the first x rows by not putting data in them and then use `ng-repeat-begin` and `ng-repeat-end`.

Answer (score 0):

Ending up with something like:

```
<table>
   <tr><th>Title</th><th>Subtitle</th><th>Value</th></tr>
   <tr ng-repeat-start="(subtitle, things) in mydata">
      <td rowspan="8" ng-if="$first">{{subtitle}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="(thing, values) in things">
      <td rowspan="4" ng-if="$first">{{thing}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="value in values">
      <td>{{value}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

But then this messes up trying to highlight every other row with different coloring in CSS (since there are now "hidden" rows).

Comment: Can't really get jsfiddle to work with angular, but this is the code:  https://jsfiddle.net/fofmv7zf/1/