# Children Filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS and I am hoping to do a tree data using filter of AngularJS.

Here is my code in HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div  ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <!-- <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | removeBlank ">
                [[ friend.name]]
              </li>
            </ul> -->
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="x in tableHeaders">
                            <label>[[ x.name ]]</label> 
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center"><label>Options</label></th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in items | childrenFilter" ng-if="!noRecord">
                        <td>[[ x.name ]]</td>
                        <td>[[ x.code ]]</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="#/update/[[ x.id ]]"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update"></span></a>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    // Change template tags
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

app.filter('childrenFilter', function(){
    return function (items){
        nodeKey = 'children';

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if(nodeKey in items[i]){
                x = items[i];
                while(nodeKey in x){
                    x = x[nodeKey];
                    for(y=0;y<x.length;y++){
                        x = x[y];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return items;
    }
});



app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        {
            "name": "Tankers",
            "code": "TANK",
            "id": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Oiler",
                    "code": "OIL",
                    "id": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "Chemical",
                    "code": "CHEM",
                    "id": 3,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Production",
                            "code": "PROD",
                            "id": 6
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Bulker",
            "code": "BULK",
            "id": 4,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Logger",
                    "code": "LOG",
                    "id": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Sterilized",
            "code": "STER",
            "id": 21
        }
    ];

    $scope.tableHeaders = [
        {'name': 'Name.'},
        {'name': 'Code'},
        {'name': 'Updated By'},
        {'name': 'Date Updated'},
    ];
});
```

To be Honest I am kinda stuck and what I want to achieve is similar to the image below. Where all the children of a certain object is appended indented and can be toggled

[image]

Comment: whats not working currently?

Comment: I'm still trying to push things in an array. To achieve  something simlar to the image

Answer (score -1):

You should have searched I little bit more on StackOverflow. I found another question of what you were trying to achieve: 
 [the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900050/angular-js-ng-repeat-across-multiple-elements) and the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNRAdQnXfhvY2fm4pxGH?p=preview).
I don't think filters could be used for your example.

In JS when you define an object, you don't need to put the quotes for the property: `name`, `code`, `id`, `children`, etc.

```
var data = [{
    name: "Tankers",
    code: "TANK",
    id: 1,
    children: [ 
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
}];
```

Also, in AngularJS you can iterate with `ng-repeat` not only on objects, but also on arrays:

```
$scope.tableHeader = ["Name", "Code", "Updated By", "Date Updated", "Options"];
```

And then:

```
<th ng-repeat="header in tableHeader">{{header}}</th>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/n33dLs1z/) with some corrections of your code.

Generally, there are lots of modules for AngularJS for various functionalities.
For example, I think [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) can help you achieve what you need.

Comment: You really did not answer the question. I used square brackets because it conflicts with my server-side template tags. I tried other modules however it conflicts with my glyphicons on the last column

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see the JS part before the controller. You should really put  the code in a fiddle.

Comment: I updated the answer. A similar question was already asked. I don't think you can use filters for your example.

Comment: I'm afraid those links you updated does not answer my question