# How to repeat two more rows to each in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The following table row is typical.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.subject}}</td>
    <td>{{item.author}}</td>
    <td>{{item.date}}</td>
</tr>
```

but, how to repeat two rows to each?

```
<tr ??>
    <td rowspan=2>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td colspan=2>{{item.subject}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ??>
    <td>{{item.author}}</td>
    <td>{{item.date}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js ng-repeat across multiple trs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979205/angular-js-ng-repeat-across-multiple-trs)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you're using AngularJS 1.2+, you can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
    <td rowspan=2>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td colspan=2>{{item.subject}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
    <td>{{item.author}}</td>
    <td>{{item.date}}</td>
</tr>
```

See "Special repeat start and end points" in the [`ngRepeat` docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat).

Otherwise, you have to resort to some nasty tricks, like wrapping the `tr`s in a `tbody` element and repeating that.