# Angular Directive - Nested Object in Attr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

There is [great solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/vGUsu/) provided for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362868/adding-rows-with-ng-repeat-and-nested-loop), that shows how to use a directive to display `<tr>`'s for nested objects. However, I need to take it a step further and pass a nested object into my attribute as well.

In the example below, I have added `obj` to my scope and the rows are now chained off `obj`. However, as soon as I do this it breaks and doesn't render any of the rows. What am I doing wrong?

My suspicion is it has to do with `scope[attrs.rows]` but I'm not positive.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-table rows='obj.rows'></my-table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html = '<table>';
            angular.forEach(scope[attrs.rows], function (row, index) {
                html += '<tr><td>' + row.name + '</td></tr>';
                if ('subrows' in row) {
                    angular.forEach(row.subrows, function (subrow, index) {
                        html += '<tr><td>' + subrow.name + '</td></tr>';
                    })
                }
            })
            html += '</table>';
            element.replaceWith(html)
        }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {
        rows = [];
    }
    $scope.obj.rows = [
        { name: 'row1', subrows: [{ name: 'row1.1' }, { name: 'row1.2' }] },
        { name: 'row2' }
    ];
}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattheye/uqNLH/1/

I'm trying to get it to work like *this* fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/vGUsu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of accessing the `rows` using `scope[attrs.rows]`, [use `scope.$eval`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24eval), like this:

```js
angular.forEach(scope.$eval(attrs.rows), function (row, index) {
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqNLH/2/)

---

However, this will *not* update after you update `rows` on `MainCtrl` because the value is read only once.

To do the binding, you would want to set up a `$watch` on `attrs.rows` instead like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uqNLH/7/

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. The $watch, however, doesn't seem to fire when adding new obj.rows. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/mattheye/uqNLH/4/

Comment: Ah, indeed. You need deep object watching to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/uqNLH/7/ In Angular 1.2, `$watchCollection` would suit your use case perfectly. However, `jsFiddle` does not allow me use it currently.