# Angularjs, two data in a single row in table

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem to implement table with thin width.

```
myData = { name:"Foo", age:11, sex:"M", weight:77, height:77, hobby:'gaming'}
```

I wanna table like belows.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>name</td><td>Foo</td><td>age</td><td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>sex</td><td>M</td><td>weight</td><td>77</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>height</td><td>77</td><td>hobby</td><td>gaming</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to show data like this using ngRepeat and its built-in variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362868/adding-rows-with-ng-repeat-and-nested-loop

Comment: In particular take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17533596/373655 to the question John posted. You can use the `tbody` trick but you won't need a nested ng-repeat

Comment: Also you need to change your object as array of object otherwise it will sorted alphabetical and `name` won't be the first `td` item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question John posted would solve your problem but I think it would be less of a hack to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` e.g.:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in myData">
       <td>name</td><td>{{item.name}}</td><td>age</td><td>{{item.age}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>sex</td><td>{{item.sex}}</td><td>weight</td><td>{{item.weight}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
       <td>height</td><td>{{item.height}}</td><td>hobby</td><td>{{item.hobby}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have yr myData like this :

```
myData = [{ name:"Foo", age:11, sex:"M", weight:77, height:77, hobby:'gaming'},{ name:"Foo", age:11, sex:"M", weight:77, height:77, hobby:'gaming'},{ name:"Foo", age:11, sex:"M", weight:77, height:77, hobby:'gaming'}]
```

Then Your table will be like this :

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in myData">
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      <td>{{row.age}}</td>
      <td>{{row.sex}}</td>
      <td>{{row.weight}}</td>
      <td>{{row.height}}</td>
      <td>{{row.hobby}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```