# AngularJS ng-repeat nested loop but unnested element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**EDIT:** Sorry this is already asked - [Adding rows with ng-repeat and nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362868/adding-rows-with-ng-repeat-and-nested-loop)

How do you do this in AngularJS?

```
foreach(var item in items) {                 <-- How to do this loop

  <tr><td>{{item.Name}}</td></tr>

  foreach(var subitem in item.subitems) {    <-- AND this loop?

    <tr class='sub'><td>{{subitem.Name}}</td></tr>

  }
}
```

Note that the `<tr>` element is **not** nested.

A possible expected result:

```
<tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
<tr class='sub'><td>Item 1.1</td></tr>
<tr class='sub'><td>Item 1.2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
```

Comment: I'd create an array containing all the rows using JavaScript code in the controller, and use a single ng-repeat in the view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding rows with ng-repeat and nested loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362868/adding-rows-with-ng-repeat-and-nested-loop)

Comment: why you dont think of `ng-repeat` to use here

Comment: I would follow this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362868/adding-rows-with-ng-repeat-and-nested-loop/17533596#17533596?newreg=abc0203e45e043c4ba0e14242143af45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using `tbody` element as the first `ng-repeat` container, like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
    <tr><td>{{item.Name}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub" ng-repeat="subitem in item.subitems">
      <td>{{subitem.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```