# angularJS - Repeating tr's in a table, but dynamically adding more rows while looping

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Since examples always tell more then just words here is what I would like to do in another language

```
<tr>
    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item"> 
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <c:if test="${item.showWarning}">
         </tr><tr><td colspan="3">${item.warning}</td>
      </c:if>
</tr>
```

So this will loop over a set of items and show some properties of these items. If there is a warning, a new row will be added underneath the current row in which the warning will be shown. However, how can I do this in angularJs? If I put a ng-repeat on the tr, it will stop at the first end tag of tr. I have read on some other threads that this is not very easily done, but how can it be done? And yes, I really do want to use a table. Here is my contrived example with angularjs which is obviously not working as I would like it to. Any pointers how this can be done?

[JSBin example with tr-ng-repeat](http://jsbin.com/owefez/3/edit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution that I can think of is having multiple `tbody` tags within the same table. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table) is a discussion on the use of multiple `tbody` tags within the same table.

So, for your issue, you could have the following setup:

```
<table ng-controller="ItemController">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>warning?</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
            <td>{{item.warning}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="item.warning">
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">Warning !!!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Repeat the table body as many times as there are entries for the table and within it have two rows - one to actually display the row entry and one to be displayed conditionally.

Answer (score 20):

Currently **(1.0.7/1.1.5)** you ***can't*** output data outside the ng-repeat, ***but*** version **1.2**(see youtube video [AngularJS 1.2 and Beyond](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W13qDdJDHp8) at 17:30) will bring the following syntax(adapted to your example):

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="item.showWarning">
  <td colspan="3">{{item.warning}}</td>
</tr>
```

The idea is that whatever is between **-start** and **-end** will be repeated including the **-end** element.

Comment: indeed, then I will wait for 1.2 to do it this way and until then use the tbody repeat "solution". Thx for the info though

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat over the `tbody`

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
  <tr>
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>{{item.description}}</td>
   <td>{{item.warning}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-show="item.warning">
    <td colspan="3">Warning !!!</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also you do not need to wrap the `ng-show` expression in `{{}}`, you can just use `item.warning`