# html: can table rows be grouped?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to toggle visibility on certain rows in a table.

I know I should probably redo the table as list items, 
but is possible to do something like this:

```
<rowgroup data-id='1'>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
</rowgroup>

<rowgroup data-id='2'>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
</rowgroup>
```

Comment: tbody - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html

Comment: @rid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>...</tr>
   ...
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

A table may have multiple `<tbody>` elements, but it may only have one `<thead>` and one `<tfoot>`.

Comment: That's why I love SO. Thanks !