# angularjs: ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end with inner ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have a simple use case for ng-repeat-start and end and is working just fine, the problem appears when I want to add an inner ng-repeat.
Here is the my code

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="obj in rows" >
  <td ng-repeat="e in obj.row">{{e}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
  <td colspan="4">{{obj.description}}</td>
<tr>
```

The inner ng-repeat into td element is not working, I'm seeing the ngRepeat comment when I inspect the html source code, but the td elements are not being created.

```
<!-- ngRepeat: e in obj.row -->
```

My ugly workaround (given that I know the size of that vector) is:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="obj in rows" >
  <td>{{obj.row[0]}}</td>
  <td>{{obj.row[1]}}</td>
  <td>{{obj.row[2]}}</td>
  <td>{{obj.row[3]}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
  <td colspan="4">{{obj.description}}</td>
<tr>
```

Comment: Is it because the template is invalid HTML? I see the ending `</tr>` tag is actually `<tr>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure whether you are using angular 1.1.6 or not since `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` are not available in 1.1.5 or 1.0.7 yet.

However, you don't actually have to use the new directives to achieve that. You can simply implement it like this for right now:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="obj in rows">
        <tr ng-repeat="e in obj.row">
            <td>{{e}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">{{obj.description}}</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You may use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to reimplement it when AngularJS 1.1.6 version is officially released.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F5UCC/)**</kbd>

Comment: Yes I'm using version 1.1.6. 
I like your solution I tried it before and it worked. What I don't like is the multiple tbody elements, because of that I give a try to this new feature.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Jime You need one `tbody` only.

Comment: @EliranMalka Thank you. Just want to make it more professional and easy to read :)

Comment: @sza the html code generated by that ng-repeat at tbody level will create several tbody elements.
here is the code generated by your example (which is really good and useful)
<table>
<!-- ngRepeat: obj in rows -->
<tbody ng-repeat="obj in rows" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: e in obj.row -->
<tr ng-repeat="e in obj.row" class="ng-scope">
</tbody>
<tbody ng-repeat="obj in rows" class="ng-scope">
<!-- ngRepeat: e in obj.row --><tr ng-repeat="e in obj.row" class="ng-scope">
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: Multiple tbody's seems to be valid according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table

Comment: implementing like this would not let datatable work properly. as datatable is working for 1 tbody.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be something wrong with your data structure. Using Angular **1.2.1** this works for me

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="h" ng-repeat-start="val in data">{{val.title}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="con in val.content">
        {{con}}
    </div>
    <div class="b" ng-repeat-end>footer</div>
</div>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pcQF/)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use index-based iterations to bypass that:

```html
<tr ng-repeat-start="obj in rows" >
  <td ng-repeat="e in obj.row">{{obj.row[$index]}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: the problem is that the ng-repeat directive is not being resolved, either I use index based iteration or e object