# Using readHTMLTable with multiple tbody

Tags: html, r

Suppose I have an HTML table with multiple `<tbody>`, which [we know is perfectly legal HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table), and attempt to read it with `readHTMLTable` as follows:

```
library(XML)
table.text <- '<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1a</td><td>2a</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1b</td><td>2b</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>'
readHTMLTable(table.text)
```

The output I get only takes the first `<tbody>` element:

```
$`NULL`
  Col1 Col2
1   1a   2a
```

and ignores the rest. Is this expected behavior? (I can't find any mention in the documentation.) And **what are the most flexible and robust ways to access the entire table?**

I'm currently using

```
table.text <- gsub('</tbody>[[:space:]]*<tbody>', '', table.text)
readHTMLTable(table.text)
```

which prevents me from using `readHTMLTable` directly on a URL to get a table like this, and also doesn't feel very robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source for `readHTMLTable` `getMethod(readHTMLTable, "XMLInternalElementNode")` it contains the line

```
    if (length(tbody)) 
        node = tbody[[1]]
```

so it is purposefully designed to select only the content of the first tbody. Also `?readHTMLTable` describes the function as providing

> somewhat robust methods for extracting data from HTML tables in an HTML document

It is designed to be a utility function. Its great when it works but you may need to hack around it.

Comment: Fair enough, but I wish the documentation mentioned this behavior.