# Render an HTML table having multiple tbody elements using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to render a table in html using Ajax data payload.
The ajax data structure is as follows:-

```
{"id":733,
 "lastUpdatedBy":"4",
 "lastUpdatedTime":"2013-11-24 03:00:03PM",
 "jobName":"jobnameA",
 "accountName":"accountname1A"
}
```

The Html for the table to be rendered is as follows:-

```
    <table id="main_table">
       <thead>
        <tr class="firstline">
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
        <td  colspan="4" class="flip" id="fisrtsec"> Test Account 19 </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
    <tr>

        <td>item id</td>
        <td>item jobName</td>
        <td>item accountName</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
        <td>item 121</td>
        <td>item 122</td>
        <td>item 123</td>
        <td>item 124</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
        <td>item 131</td>
        <td>item 132</td>
        <td>item 133</td>
        <td>item 134</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     <tbody>
     <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
        <td  colspan="4" class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
     <td></td>
        <td>item 211</td>
        <td>item 212</td>
        <td>item 213</td>
        <td>item 214</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td></td>
        <td>item 221</td>
        <td>item 222</td>
        <td>item 223</td>
        <td>item 224</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
     <td></td>
        <td>item 231</td>
        <td>item 232</td>
        <td>item 233</td>
        <td>item 234</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

Am using Jquery library. My jquery is

```
 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $('<tr><td>ID: '+key+'</td><td id="'+key+'">'+val+'</td>   
  <tr>').appendTo('#main_table');
     });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for looking.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some markup at the top of your HTML section. And do you have any JavaScript code to post? What have you tried? What frameworks/libraries are you using, if any?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having multiple `tbody`'s is valid markup. Having said that, try.

```
('<tr><td>ID: '+key+'</td><td id="'+key+'">'+val+'</td><tr>')
  .appendTo('#main_table tbody:last');
```

Using `:last` will append at the end of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried the above code. It is working fine. However, am looking to toggle the section with class 'flip' (in html table), so that I can show/hide the block - <tbody class="section">, hence the multiple <tbody> tags.

Comment: I think using multiple tbody elements should be fine. As per the question here - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table?rq=1)