# How to build a table with ng-repeat with mixed number of columns for row?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I really don't know how to succinctly describe what I'm trying to do so sorry for the bad title.  But I have a table where I want to interlace different types of rows.  I have one row that mirrors the columns across the top, and I have another row that spans all columns to show the year.

For example:

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>11/30/2013</td>
         <td>Some Description</td>
         <td>$1450.00</td>
         ...
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>12/31/2013</td>
         <td>Some Description</td>
         <td>$1450.00</td>
         ...
     </tr>
     <tr colspan="9">2014</tr>
     <tr>
         <td>1/31/2014</td>
         <td>Some Description</td>
         <td>$1450.00</td>
         ...
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the straightforward implementation to put all of the data in the table:

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="paycheck in paychecks">
         <td>{{paycheck.payDate}}</td>
         <td>{{paycheck.description}}</td>
         <td>{{paycheck.amount}}</td>
         ...
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I'd like to put this row between those rows when I traverse over a yearly boundary:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="9" ng-if="paycheck.payDate.year > previousPaycheck.payDate.year">{{paycheck.payDate.year}}</td>
</tr>
```

This means I'd have to put two rows in the table when the above condition is true, but with ng-repeat I'm only adding one.  I suspect I'll have to rebuild my data structure such that I insert the year boundaries in it so ng-repeat will be a 1:1 with rows in the table and elements in my array.  Or maybe some special directive magic that could make this easier.

Is there an easy way to do this that I don't see?

Comment: can you post some sample data for paychecks object please

Comment: The data in paychecks isn't material to the answer because it's a bunch of properties (one of which is the date as illustrated above), and those properties are put in a series of columns for each row.  I've included enough of the properties in the example for you to guess what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.

```
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="paycheck in paychecks">
        <td colspan="9" ng-if="paycheck.payDate.year > paychecks[$index-1].payDate.year">  {{paycheck.payDate.year}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end>
         <td>{{paycheck.payDate}}</td>
         <td>{{paycheck.description}}</td>
         <td>{{paycheck.amount}}</td>
      </tr>          
</tbody>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/USToUVcuo5tV0VR0Vn9B?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` has a few variables it attaches to the scope on each iteration, one being `$index`.

Leveraging this, you could do something like:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="date in data">
      <tr ng-show='$index == 0 || data[$index].year != data[$index-1].year'>
        <td colspan="3">{{date.year}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{date.year}}</td>
        <td>{{date.month}}</td>
        <td>{{date.day}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/axuKJTuTii1v8M4cX5Dk

Note that this requires your data to be sorted.

Comment: This will give you a separate `tbody` for each paycheck, which may not be what you want.

Comment: A minor detail that's irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: Not irrelevant if you have css styling the table that isn't expecting multiple tbody tags.

Comment: I'm merely suggesting the asker to look at the logic, not to copy/paste the solution into his own work.

Comment: Maybe the asker actually _wants_ multiple groups in the table, in which case this method would be preferable.  But his desired output only indicates a single `tbody`.

Comment: No Jerrad is correct.  Not having extra nodes is important to the solution so not having multiple tbodies or multiple tr tags that are just hidden is a no go.  I could figure that those solutions on my own.  I knew how to do it inefficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Here is a working solution in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/a55krX8x9G1e5MGUIz0A?p=preview

Logic:
Firstly the data has to be in the ordered by the `payDate` for this to work

```
   <tbody ng-repeat="paycheck in paychecksOrdered">
      <tr ng-show="header(paycheck, $index)">
        <td colspan="9">{{paycheck.payDate | date:'yyyy'}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{{paycheck.payDate}}</td>
        <td>{{paycheck.description}}</td>
        <td>{{paycheck.amount}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>



  $scope.paychecksOrdered = $filter('date')(paychecks, 'payDate');
  $scope.header = function(paycheck, i) {
    if (i === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    console.log(i);
    var past = $scope.paychecksOrdered[i - 1].payDate.getFullYear(),
      cur = paycheck.payDate.getFullYear();
    console.log(cur, past);
    return past != cur;
  };
```

Comment: Like the other answer, this will give you a separate `tbody` for each paycheck, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Using ng-repeat on tbody appears to be valid see this post -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table

Comment: Not saying it isn't valid, just saying you might end up with a table that you aren't expecting.

Comment: I'm ok with either wise to use ng-repeat or using start/end tags. And this is just a solution to the question. And even html validators permit multiple tbody elements inside a table. Though I'm not sure how this will result in an unexpected table. Applying CSS will be trivial here I guess.

Comment: Why fill the DOM with unnecessary tags?

Comment: I'm looking for something that doesn't repeat the tbody element and inserts the minimal amount of nodes.  Using ng-show/hide will double the count of nodes in the DOM for the size of paychecks.  I want something more efficient which Jerrad answered.