# How to expand table row in Ember 1.8?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to make my row expanded on click. Similar effect takes place [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mfwYS/embedded/result/). The problem is that I am getting `tr` inside `tr` when using `each` on new handlebars 1.8.

```
{{#each positions itemController='position' itemView='url'}}
    <td>{{position}}

    {{#if showExpanded}}
         {{render 'positionDetails' this}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}

App.UrlView = Ember.View.extend
    tagName: 'tr'

App.PositionDetailsView = Ember.View.extend
    tagName: 'tr'
```

Results:

```
<tr class="ember-view" id="ember7755">
   <td>1</td>
   <tr class="position-details-view">
</tr>
```

How can I make it works? 
I've manged to create only expending function

```
App.PositionDetailsView = Ember.View.extend
    tagName: 'tr'
    classNames: 'expanded'

    didInsertElement: (->
        parent = @.$().parent()

        @.$().show().detach().insertAfter(parent)
```

Comment: It looks like you're setting the `tagName` for `PositionDetailsView` to 'tr', so a `<tr>` element for the DetailsView would be the expected result. Did you mean to use 'td' instead?

Comment: No, I don't. Please look at the effect demo. I need to move `tr.details.view` just after each parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing code, you will always have one `tr` nested inside the other because the `itemView` for the `each` has `tagName: 'tr'`, while the positionDetailsView nested inside of it also has the `tagName` set to 'tr'.

For the results you want, you need a (non-tr) item view that contains *both* of the `<tr>` elements. However because it's a table, the default `div` element for Ember views won't work. Fortunately we can nest the rows in a `tbody`, and (more importantly)  [we can have multiple tbody elements in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table).

That would lead us to this:

```
{{#each positions itemController='position' itemView='url'}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{position}}</td>
  </tr>

  {{#if showExpanded}}
     {{render 'positionDetails' this}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}

App.UrlView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'tbody'

App.PositionDetailsView = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'tr'
```

This assumes you want to keep `UrlView` as the entire section for a single element of `positions`. If not, you can keep the old `UrlView`, define a separate view to be the `tbody`, and wrap the position `td` above with `{{#view 'App.UrlView'}}...{{/view}}` instead of `tr`.

In any event, I would not recommend manually manipulating the DOM when using Ember views, as suggested by your edited question. But that code should no longer be necessary with these changes.

Comment: The thing is that I can't use other tag than `tr` inside `tbody`. Ember will default use `div` which is going to break my layout.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Would it be possible in your case to remove the existing `tbody`, and make the itemView a `tbody`? [It's possible to have multiple tbody elements in a single table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table) (though I presume they can't be nested).

Comment: Yes, indeed. Multiple `tbody` is the solution that I was looking for. Thanks for your time ;).

Comment: No problem! I've updated the answer to reflect these comments.