# Wrapper for multiple <tbody>?

Tags: html, css

For specific css requirements I'm using multiple `<tbody>` tags in my table design which looks something like this:

[**Use of multiple tbody tags**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLe1w3zp/1/)

But I also require a ***wrapper for multiple tbody tags*** (something like a common tbody parent) such that this ***wrapper can be scrolled*** in order achieve the following effect:

[**A common tbody which can be scrolled**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmxgL4uy/)

How do I achieve the latter srolling effect in the former one?

(P.S.: I know this can be done through nested table approach, but I'm looking for other alternatives if any)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table

Comment: @lolka_bolka that question deals with the possibility of having multiple tbody tags. I have just implemented the most upvoted answer in my first fiddle. What i required was a WRAPPER for multiple tbody  tags.

Comment: The only valid wrapper is the table element, and it also encloses thead, tfoot and all tbody of course.

Comment: Just use a <table> as your wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by FelipeAls and others that a `<tbody>` tag can be wrapped only by a `<table>` tag, I tried wrapping `<thead>` and `<tbody>`s in separate tables to create the desired effect in the following way:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This solved the issue.

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLe1w3zp/2/)**.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a wrapper for `tbody` elements inside a table. The `tbody` element itself is a wrapper for `tr` elements. HTML syntax does not allow any other container for `tbody` but `table`. What matters more is that this syntax rules is actually enforced by the way browsers parse HTML.

If you try to use, say, a `div` element as a wrapper (the most reasonable approach), it will actually create a `div` element in the DOM, but an empty one, and *before* the table. All the `tbody` and `tr` elements are inserted into the `table` element; they are effectively extracted from the `div` element, which thus becomes empty, unless it contains something else than table-related elements.

An illustration, using intentionally invalid markup:

```html
<style>
.x { outline: solid red }
</style>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>foo
</tbody>
<div class=x>
FOO!
<tbody>
<tr><td>foo2
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr><td>foo3
</tbody>
</div>
<tbody>
<tr><td>The end
</tbody>
</table>
```

The conclusion is that you need a different approach. The most obvious one is to use just a single `tbody` element. If this is not feasible, you should explain why, but this would be a topic for a new question.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, I need separate tbody tags to wrap two rows (one containing cells and other containing a textual row- which may be absent/present, as I have shown in the fiddle) so that I can apply specific css to these two rows collectively irrespective of the presence/absence of the textual row.

Comment: You didn’t mention that in the question. In any case, styling of some adjacent `tr` elements is possible without a wrapper. If you think you have a different case, it should be explained *in the question itself*, in a new question. As regards to the question asked here, I think my answer is a correct one.