# Use Less or CSS to repeat previous sibling's style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors, less

### Question

Is there a clean way to apply a style for all sibling elements between two HTML elements?

### Background

I have a table with bootstrap's `.table-striped` class, however, I want an arbitrary number of rows to be striped together as a group.  My solution was to create a custom element using

```
document.registerElement("seq-tr");
```

and extend the `tr:nth-child(odd/even)` to `tr:nth-of-type(odd/even)`, as well as to `...tr:nth-of-type(odd/even) + seq-tr`:

```
.table.table-striped {
    > thead, tbody, tfoot {
        > tr {
            ~ seq-tr > td {
                border-top: none;
                padding-top: 0;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            &:nth-of-type(even) {
                &, + seq-tr {
                    background-color: @table-bg;
                }
            }

            &:nth-of-type(odd) {
                &, + seq-tr {
                    &:extend(.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd));

                    > td:extend(.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aside: Originally I had tried using the `~` selector instead of `+`, but that applied both `:nth-of-type(even)` and `:nth-of-type(odd)` to every `<seq-tr>` after the second row and whichever was later in the compiled CSS file took precedent, rather than being smart about it and looking for whether the closest sibling `<tr>` was even or odd.

So the above code works for the first `<seq-tr>` element, but for the following `<seq-tr>`s, it does not.

Is there a clever way to make this work for any number of consecutive `<seq-tr>`s?

I could use a `seq-tr.striped` class, but I would rather not.

### Edit

It just occurred to me I could simply use multiple `<tbody>` elements, and style the rows based on even/oddness of those, rather than the rows themselves.

[Can we have multiple <tbody> in same <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table)

I'd still like the answer to my question for other purposes, but it's less pressing now.

Comment: The potential advantage of the `tbody` option is that it may enhance accessibility.

Comment: as far as i understand there is not wrong with your `&:nth-of-type(even) {
                &, + seq-tr {`, also see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPExMZ. So possible some BS table styles with a higher specificity override you styles? Could you create a live example which shows the issue?