# angularjs ng-repeat tbody duplicate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, document-body

I am unable to find a solution, also  I cannot change data schema and i cannot have duplicated tbdoy because i use scrollable tbody
so any one have any idea ?

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th><?php echo $conf->get('text.phone_number', 'Phone Number'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $conf->get('text.group_subject', 'Group Subject'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $conf->get('text.categories', 'categories'); ?> ...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="data in shared.data">
        <tr ng-repeat="group in data.groups" class="representor">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{data.provider.number}}</td>
            <td>{{group.subject}}</td>
            <td ng-if="! group.categories"><a  href="#" ng-click="addCategoryClick(group)">הוסף קטגוריה</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you get when you run this?

Comment: its multiple the tbody but the problem i can't do the repeats without dupe the tbody

Comment: I don't see why this is a problem ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table

Comment: the problem im doing the the tbody scrollable

Comment: @LeonidVinikov you should mention that in your question then

Comment: Sounds like tables aren't going to be a viable solution then. I'd use a grid system like [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) `row` and `col-` classes

Answer (score 2):

Simply add another attribute to scope as `myData` and  add a method like :

```
$scope.getData = function() {       
    $scope.myData = [];
    $scope.shared.data.forEach(function(sData){
        sData.forEach(function(group){
            $scope.myData.push({sData: sData, group: group});
        });
    });
}
```

and html modified to:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="datum in getData()" class="representor">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{datum.sData.provider.number}}</td>
        <td>{{datum.group.subject}}</td>
        <td ng-if="! datum.group.categories"><a  href="#" ng-click="addCategoryClick(datum.group)">הוסף קטגוריה</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

doubt this would reduce the performance in a significant manner