# What does h:dataTable bodyrows attribute mean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

Does anybody know what `h:dataTable bodyrows` means? I tried a simple example, but I don't understand what it's supposed to do.

```
<h:dataTable bodyrows="d" value="#{index.publishDates}" var="d">
```

Is this some sort of shortcut for making a table? I don't see any rows because of the `bodyrows` annotation. If `h:column` does columns, what does `bodyrows` do?

I don't understand [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html).

> This must be a comma separated list of integers. Each entry in this list is the row index of the row before which a "tbody" element should be rendered.

Comment: It is exactly what it says in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html).

Comment: There is also "If the current row index is contained in the "bodyrows" attribute, check if a "tbody" start element was rendered that needs to be closed, and if so, close the "tbody" element. Then render a "tbody" element start. Otherwise, do not render a "tbody" element." If you've read all this why are you setting it to `"d"`?

Comment: That doesn't explain it to me. Example anyone?

Comment: play with it and look at the generated HTML... EJP is complete right. This results,clientside, in multiple tbody tags in a table.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table. Understanding basic html and css is required when using jsf...

Comment: Thank you all, I was able to sort out what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, a `<table>` can have multiple bodies via [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody).

```
<table>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

By default, a `<h:datatable>` generates only one body like below.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{[1,2,3,4,5]}" var="i">
    <h:column>#{i}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The [`bodyrows`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/dataTable.html) attribute can be used to specify a commaseparated string of row indexes which should start as a new body.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{[1,2,3,4,5]}" var="i" bodyrows="0,2,4">
    <h:column>#{i}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### See also:

- [Can we have multiple <tbody> in same <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table)
- [HTML Dog HTML beginner tutorial - tables](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/tables/)
- [MDN HTML element reference - table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

Comment: Awesome example Mr. C. Thanks for taking the time.