# Change standard behavior of Angular2 Component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have a Component with table template.

This is part:

```
<tr *ngFor="let stat of statistic" class="stripped">
        <td>{{stat.date         | date:"shortDate"}}</td> 
        <td>{{stat.hits         | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.unique       | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.registrations| number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.conversion   | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.deposit      | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.ftd          | number }}</td>
        <td class="bold">{{stat. deals | number }}</td>
        <td class="bold colored">{{stat.profit| currency:'USD':true:'1.2' }}</td>
</tr>
```

But instead of tr I need to insert two. If I try to use it as another component, a table breaks.

Is there a tricky way to insert another tr after each tr in cycle? Or maybe has a way of exchange Component selector on his template

Comment: you want to use `*ngFor` twice on tr ?

Comment: @PardeepJain yes and no) I need to insert two tr with same data but different structure.

Comment: Using bootstrap grid system instead of table can do the trick

Comment: @Illorian check my answer please

Comment: @ArunGhosh 
Unfortunately I must use table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said in comment you want to use same data but want two `tr` so you can try this one :-

```
<template ngFor let-stat [ngForOf]='statistic'>
    <tr class="stripped">
        <td>{{stat.date | date:"shortDate"}}</td>
        <td>{{stat.hits | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.unique | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.registrations| number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.conversion | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.deposit | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.ftd | number }}</td>
        <td class="bold">{{stat. deals | number }}</td>
        <td class="bold colored">{{stat.profit| currency:'USD':true:'1.2' }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="stripped">
        <td>{{stat.date | date:"shortDate"}}</td>
        <td>{{stat.hits | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.unique | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.registrations| number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.conversion | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.deposit | number }}</td>
        <td>{{stat.ftd | number }}</td>
        <td class="bold">{{stat. deals | number }}</td>
        <td class="bold colored">{{stat.profit| currency:'USD':true:'1.2' }}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

see here for more tricky way of using *ngFor in angular2
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: Thanks. I really forgot about templates

Answer (score 0):

You can use tbody

```
<tbody *ngFor="let stat of statistic" class="stripped">
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

Form this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table) you can have multiple tbody in a table.

Using bootstrap grid system instead of table can do the trick.

Comment: Is think it's not valid layout

Comment: @Illorian its valid but this does't make sense to repeat `tbody` may cause some design issue later so better to use `template` that we already have.