# How do I wrap a React component that returns multiple table rows and avoid the "<tr> cannot appear as a child of <div>" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called OrderItem that takes an object with multiple objects (at least two) inside it, and renders them as multiple rows inside a table.  There will be multiple OrderItem components inside the table. The problem is that in the component's render function, I can't return multiple  lines.  I can only return a single component, and if I wrap them in a div, it says " `<tr>` cannot appear as a child of `<div>`"

The code looks something like this (I left some stuff out for easier readability)

```js
Parent() {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {
            _.map(this.state.orderItems, (value, key) => {
              return <OrderItem value={value} myKey={key}/>
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

class OrderItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div> // <-- problematic div
        <tr key={this.props.myKey}>
          <td> Table {this.props.value[0].table}</td>
          <td> Item </td>
          <td> Option </td>
        </tr>
        {this.props.value.map((item, index) => {
          if (index > 0) { // skip the first element since it's already used above
            return (
              <tr key={this.props.myKey + index.toString()}>
                <td><img src={item.image} alt={item.name} width="50"/> {item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.selectedOption}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          }
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can return those multiple rows and have them be in the same table without wrapping them in a div and getting an error?  I realize I can make a separate table for each component, but that throws my formatting off a bit.

Comment: One option might be to remove the top level tbody tag.  Then let map return in a <tbody> tag.

Comment: That seems pretty similar to the solution below with multiple table tags, just with tbody instead of table.

Comment: I believe this is possible now with the use of https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is no way to wrap them cleanly, so the easier solution is to just put the whole table in the component and just have multiple tables and figure out the formatting.

```js
Parent() {
   render() {
       return (
           {_.map(this.state.orderItems, (value, key) => {
               return <OrderItem value={value} myKey={key} key={key}/>
           })}
       )
   }
}


class OrderItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td> Table {this.props.value[0].table}</td>
                       <td> Item </td>
                       <td> Option </td>
                    </tr>
                    {this.props.value.map((item, index) => {
                        if (index > 0) { // skip the first element since it's already used above
                            return (
                                <tr key={this.props.myKey + index.toString()}>
                                    <td> <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} width="50"/> {item.name}</td>  
                                    <td>{item.selectedOption}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        }
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

`React 16` is now here to rescue, you can now use `React.Fragment` to render list of elements without wrapping it into a parent element. You can do something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <tr>
        ...
      </tr>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: ```<React.Fragment>``` seems to work a lot better than ```<tbody>``` too from my experience.

Answer (score 30):

Yes!! It is possible to map items to multiple table rows inside a table. A solution which doesn't throw console errors and semantically is actually correct, is to use a `tbody` element as the root component and fill with as many rows as required.

```
items.map(item => (
   <tbody>
       <tr>...</tr>
       <tr>...</tr>
   </tbody>
))
```

The following post deals with the ethical questions about it and explains why *yes we can* use multiple `tbody` elements
[Can we have multiple <tbody> in same <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table)

Comment: For the record this seemed like a great idea at the time but in react 16 we can and should use fragments instead.

Answer (score 14):

One approach is to split `OrderItem` into two components, moving the rendering logic into a method `Parent.renderOrderItems`:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  renderOrderItems() {
    const rows = []
    for (let orderItem of this.state.orderItems) {
      const values = orderItem.value.slice(0)
      const headerValue = values.shift()
      rows.push(
        <OrderItemHeaderRow table={headerValue.table} key={orderItem.key} />
      )
      values.forEach((item, index) => {
        rows.push(
          <OrderItemRow item={item} key={orderItem.key + index.toString()} />
        )
      })
    }
    return rows
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          { this.renderOrderItems() }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

class OrderItemHeaderRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td> Table {this.props.table}</td>
        <td> Item </td>
        <td> Option </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

class OrderItemRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { item } = this.props
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} width="50"/>
          {item.name}
        </td>
        <td>
          {item.selectedOption}
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It seems that it would be a bit less complicated to just put the table inside the one component though.

Answer (score 4):

It is an old question, but maybe someone stumbles on it. Since I cannot comment yet, here is a little addition to the answer of @trevorgk:

I used this to render a table with multiple rows per item (about 1000 items resulting in about 2000 rows with 15 columns) and noticed really bad performance with Firefox (even in 57).

I had pure components rendering each item (one <body> per item containing two rows each) and each item contained a (controlled) checkbox.

When clicking the checkbox Firefox took more than ten seconds to update - although only one item was actually updated due to pure components. Chrome's update took at most half a second.

I switched to React 16 and I noticed no difference. Then I used the new AWESOME!!! feature of returning an array from a component's render function and got rid of the 1000 <tbody> elements. Chrome's performance was approximately the same while Firefox's "skyrocketed" to about half a second for an update (no perceived difference to Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the solution was to return an array instead of a fragment:

```
    return [
        <TrHeader />,
        <TrRows />
    ];
```