# ReactJS nested loop inside table's tbody

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having difficulty in a nested loop. My data is like this. You can see in the comment in the middle of my table, I tried to loop again the 'detail_info' but I can't make it. **Please check the picture example output below the code.**

I can't make the third loop in my second loop. Error says:
 **JSX expressions must have one parent element.**

```
const data = 
  [{
     'product': {'value': 'Cotton'},
     'detail': [{'document_no': 'DO234','quantity': '55',
              'detail_info':[{'id': '1','expiry_date': '2018/10/12'},
                            {'id': '2','expiry_date': '2019/9/9'}]
              }]
  }]
     <table className='scroll-table'>
                <thead style={{'display':'table','width':'100%'}}> 
                    <tr> 
                        <th style={{'width':'20%'}}>Product</th>
                        <th style={{'width':'8%'}}>Doc. No</th>
                        <th style={{'width':'8%'}}>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {data.map((item,idx)=>{
                    return(
                    <tbody key={idx} className="scrollbar">
                       <tr>
                        <td style={{'width':'2%'}}><input name="product" type="text" /></td>
                       </tr>
                     {item.detail.map((i,index)=>{
                         return(
                             <tr key={index} >
                                 <td colSpan="2"></td>
                                 <td>{i.document_no}</td>
                                 <td >{i.quantity}</td>
                             </tr>
                         /*  I want to loop here to make another <tr> but I 
                           cant because **JSX expressions must have one parent element. 

                            {i.detail_info.map((a,b)=>{
                            return( 
                             <tr key={b}><td>{a.expiryDate}</td></tr>
                             )})
                         */
                         )
                     })
                </tbody>
                    )
                })}
            </table>
```

**It should look like this.**

[image]

Comment: Which version of react are you using

Comment: You can use `<React.Fragment>` for wrapping both `<tr>` if you are using a new version of React.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am using react 0.14.7, I can't yet upgrade it to the latest because it is connected to our backend django and there are lot of dependencies also that are also conflict when I tried to update the version of my react.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339086/warning-validatedomnesting-div-cannot-appear-as-a-child-of-tbody/45341901#45341901

Comment: Would you think guys `<React.Fragment>` is the solution for this?

Comment: @ajiejot if you use the latest version then yes, but the link that I just commented also has an alternative solution using JSX syntactic sugar. With the version of react that you use, that would be the appropriate solution for you

Comment: I'll try it. I am now configuring my webpack, so many dependencies affected since I updated my react version. I'll inform you guys when I already figured it out. Thanks

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Hi guys, it's working now in latest version (react 16) but some of my project/components conflict in react 16, do you have any idea how to fix this in 0.14.7 version of React?

Comment: return an array of elements separated by comma

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much @ShubhamKhatri.

Answer (score 0):

When you return a JSX expression, there may only be one parent element. Assuming you are using React v16, you may accomplish your task by wrapping your `<tr/>`'s in a fragment like:

```
{item.detail.map((i, index) => (
    <Fragment>
        <tr key={index}>
            <td colSpan="2"></td>
            <td>{i.document_no}</td>
            <td>{i.quantity}</td>
        </tr>
        {i.detail_info.map((a, b) => <tr key={b}>
            <td>{a.expiryDate}</td>
        </tr>)
        }
    </Fragment>
))
```

By wrapping your `<tr/>` with a `<Fragment/>` your JSX expression will have one parent elment. Please see [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).