# Related HTML tables

Tags: html, css

I have dynamic number of tables. For example I have invoice, each product inside is table. With products everything is OK, I do table-layout: fixed, set columns width, and they both seems like one table. Problems starts when I put another table for 'totals' in the bottom. I would like to use colspan to keep cell layout similar. Is there some ways to relate two tables? I'm thinking about putting invisible thead with product layout, but I don't find the way how to properly hide it.

Edit: I forgot to mention, I'm also using tbodys for some groupings, so I really need to use separated tables.

http://prntscr.com/df75n6

This is how my table looks now. As you can see there are jobs, and resources. I already use tbody to group job resources, i need additional wrapper to group jobs. Thats why I am using separated tables.

Comment: Does the totals section necessarily have to be another table?

Comment: You can have multiple tbody's in a table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table related.

Comment: Guys I forgot to mention. I know about tbody, but I already use tbody for some groupings etc. table > tbody > tr >  td isn't enaugh for my layout, thats why I am using separated tables. So yes, totals section have to be in another table necessarily.

Comment: Can you please post the code you currently have, editing rather than writing from scratch makes it easier both for us giving an answer and also for your incorporating the answer into your existing code

Comment: I put a screenshot of my table instead. Code is pretty complex, I think visible table will be more clear. So as you can see I already use my tbody to group resources of the job. Now I need to group jobs somehow, so I need additional wrapper. Thats why I am using separated tables instead tbodys. And thats why my totals goes to separated table too.