# nested json in angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, serialization, deserialization

Below is my json i want to bind this into table. Looking at the `gname: cricket` in the JSON, you can see that there are two rewards for it (Flipkart and Amazon).

[image]

Looking at the above picture, you can see that cricket rewards are printed in two `td`:s, I would like to instead create two lines for cricket, one with `Reward` flipkart an one for Amazon) So my expected output would be:

[image]

Here is my JSON.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":18,
      "gname":"Learning Ramayanam",
      "goalCategory":"Education",
      "goalSubCategory":"Half-yearly",
      "goalDesc":"good",
      "rowStatusCode":"I",
      "createID":"1",
      "createTS":null,
      "updateID":"Ram",
      "updateTS":null,
      "rewards":[  
         {  
            "rewardID":6,
            "rewardName":"Trends - 100000pts",
            "rowStatusCode":"U",
            "createID":"1",
            "createTS":1493131878000,
            "updateID":null,
            "updateTS":null
         }
      ],
      "initiatives":{  
         "initID":17,
         "initAction":"Stop",
         "startDate":"2017-04-27",
         "targetDate":"2017-04-30",
         "rowStatusCode":"U",
         "createID":"1",
         "createTS":1493294143000,
         "updateID":null,
         "updateTS":null,
         "status":"red"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":21,
      "gname":"cricket",
      "goalCategory":"Sports",
      "goalSubCategory":"Annual",
      "goalDesc":"ambition",
      "rowStatusCode":"I",
      "createID":"1",
      "createTS":null,
      "updateID":null,
      "updateTS":null,
      "rewards":[  
         {  
            "rewardID":23,
            "rewardName":"Amazon - 900000pts",
            "rowStatusCode":"U",
            "createID":"1",
            "createTS":1493386415000,
            "updateID":null,
            "updateTS":null
         },
         {  
            "rewardID":17,
            "rewardName":"Amazon - pts",
            "rowStatusCode":"D",
            "createID":"1",
            "createTS":1493360706000,
            "updateID":null,
            "updateTS":null
         }
      ],
      "initiatives":{  
         "initID":19,
         "initAction":"Start",
         "startDate":"2017-04-04",
         "targetDate":"2017-04-20",
         "rowStatusCode":"U",
         "createID":"1",
         "createTS":1493360896000,
         "updateID":null,
         "updateTS":null,
         "status":"grey"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":31,
      "gname":"Learn android nogut",
      "goalCategory":"Education",
      "goalSubCategory":"Half-yearly",
      "goalDesc":"education",
      "rowStatusCode":"I",
      "createID":"1",
      "createTS":1493219925000,
      "updateID":null,
      "updateTS":null,
      "rewards":[  

      ],
      "initiatives":{  
         "initID":22,
         "initAction":"Achieve",
         "startDate":"2017-04-04",
         "targetDate":"2017-04-13",
         "rowStatusCode":"U",
         "createID":"1",
         "createTS":1493363220000,
         "updateID":null,
         "updateTS":null,
         "status":"green"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":35,
      "gname":"Learning Japanese",
      "goalCategory":"Education",
      "goalSubCategory":"Half-yearly",
      "goalDesc":"Goal",
      "rowStatusCode":"i",
      "createID":"1",
      "createTS":1493361641000,
      "updateID":null,
      "updateTS":null,
      "rewards":[  
         {  
            "rewardID":18,
            "rewardName":"Flipkart - 5000pts",
            "rowStatusCode":"U",
            "createID":"1",
            "createTS":1493361655000,
            "updateID":null,
            "updateTS":null
         }
      ],
      "initiatives":{  
         "initID":21,
         "initAction": "Soft Skills,Communication class,Tution Center,Organic Foods,Coaching Class,Other",
         "startDate":"undefined",
         "targetDate":"undefined",
         "rowStatusCode":"U",
         "createID":"1",
         "createTS":1493363132000,
         "updateID":null,
         "updateTS":null,
         "status":"green"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for, what you want to achieve and neither what you did so far. At least from what I understood.

Comment: just see my json id=21 it have two rewards. I have to bind like this row1 -> 21,cricket,sports,sports,flipkart - pts row2-> 21,cricket,sports,sports,amazon- 900000ptspts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of `ng-container` here to reach your desired result, where we wrap each object you have inside a container. So your template would look like this:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Goal Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Rewards</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- Let's wrap each object in a ng-container -->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let goal of goals">
    <tbody>
      <!-- Iterate the rewards of each goal -->
      <tr *ngFor="let reward of goal.rewards">
        <td>{{goal.gname}}</td>
        <td>{{goal.goalCategory}}</td>
        <td>{{reward.rewardName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/D4xF5p5IA1Q0wHwrBzaH?p=preview)

Comment: As far as I know, it's not valid html to have multiple `tbody` in `table`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table According to that it's valid, but if I'm wrong, the `tbody`s can both be replaced with `ng-container` as well :)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1 Ah yeah, it's apparently valid according to the html 4.0.1 spec.