# How to have nested loops with map in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I can't achieve to have two nested `map`:

```jsx
render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(this.state.templates).map(function(template_name) {
            return (
              <tr key={template_name}><td><b>Template: {template_name}</b></td></tr>

              {this.state.templates[template_name].items.map(function(item) {
                return (
                  <tr key={item.id}><td>{item.id}</td></tr>
                )
              })}
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
```

This gives a `SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token`.

**How do you nest `map` calls in JSX?**

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: @MattHolland React 16.1.1

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You need to wrap it inside an element.

Something like this (I've added an extra `tr` due to the rules of tables elements):

```
  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(templates).map(function (template_name) {
            return (
              <tr key={template_name}>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <b>Template: {template_name}</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                {templates[template_name].items.map(function (item) {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                      <td>{item}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Running Example (without a table):

```js
const templates = {
  template1: {
    items: [1, 2]
  },
  template2: {
    items: [2, 3, 4]
  },
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    {
      Object.keys(templates).map(template_name => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>{template_name}</div>
            {
              templates[template_name].items.map(item => {
                return(<div>{item}</div>)
              })
            }
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, using an element to wrap things made it work. Although, I didn't exactly use your solution because nested `<tr>` is not valid, according to http://validator.w3.org/nu/. Instead, I've wrapped things with the `<tbody>`, and having several `<tbody>` in a single table is valid HTML (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076790/3486743). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Key here is to use 2 `return` statements

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if it's correct technically, but as a **mnemonic** you can remember that: "***Every returned JSX element must be only one JSX element***".

**So most of the times just wrapping what you have in a `<></>` pair (or any other arbitrary tag pair) will fix the issue.** E.g., if you're returning two `<div>`s from the render method of a component, that will be incorrect, however, if you wrap these two in a `<></>` pair, *most probably* it will be fixed.

But notice that sometimes it can get a bit more vague, e.g., when nesting two ES6 maps in each other, for example:

```js
<tbody>
{
  this.categorizedData.map(
    (catgGroup) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{catgGroup}</td>
      </tr>
      this.categorizedData[catgGroup].map(
        (item) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.price}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
</tbody>
```

Can be fixed like this:

```js
<tbody>
{
  this.categorizedData.map(
    (catgGroup) => (
      <> // <--- Notice this, it will wrap all JSX elements below in one single JSX element.
        <tr>
          <td>{catgGroup}</td>
        </tr>
        {this.categorizedData[catgGroup].map( // <--- Also notice here, we have wrapped it in curly braces, because it is an "expression" inside JSX.
          (item) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.price}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        )}
      </>
    )
  )
}
</tbody>
```

---

**P.S.**: (From [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children)): You can also return an array of elements from a React component:

```js
render() {
  // No need to wrap list items in an extra element!
  return [
    // Don't forget the keys :slight_smile:
    <li key="A">First item</li>,
    <li key="B">Second item</li>,
    <li key="C">Third item</li>,
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I struggled for a while to get my nested map function to work only to discover that what you `return` is critical. Make sure you are returning the second map itself and not just the final expected output:

```
let { categories } = data;

categories = categories.map(category =>
    category.subcategories.map((subcategory, i) => <h2 key={i}>{subcategory.name}</h2>)
);

return (
    <div className="category-container">
        <div>{categories}</div>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the return type should be an array but not an object in React16. You could try like this below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      templates: {
        foo: {
          items: [
            {id: 0},{id:1}
          ]
        },
        bar: {
          items: [
            {id: 2},{id:3}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  renderTemplate = (template, name) => {
    let data = []
    data = template.items
    data.unshift({ name: name })
    return data.map((item, index) => <tr key={index}><td>{item.name ? item.name : item.id}</td></tr>)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(this.state.templates).map(name => {
            return this.renderTemplate(this.state.templates[name], name)
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
td {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```