# Iterate Item Inside JSX React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am using nativebase and want to render two columns in a row with loop. Something like this:

```
<Row>
    <Col>item 1</Col>
    <Col>item 2</Col>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Col>item 3</Col>
    <Col>item 4</Col>
</Row>
```

How can I achieve it in JSX ?

Comment: I am trying to render nested loop over array objects like two dimensional array. Duplicate link is not similar to my question.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402365/how-to-have-nested-loops-with-map-in-jsx) for nested loop.