# Multiple recursive <tbody> in same <table>?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, tree, treeview, jsx

I want to do treeview rendering in React. I have `TreeNode` class, which does recursively renders children. So basically I want to go like this:

```
class TreeNode extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let nestedLevel = this.props.level || 0;
        let childNodes = this.props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
            return <TreeNode key={index} node={node} level={nestedLevel+1} />
        });
        let identationMargin={margin: (nestedLevel*16)+"px"};
        return (
            <tr className="treeview-row">
                <td><span style={identationMargin} />User {this.props.node.name}</td>
            </tr>
            {childNodes}
        );
    }
}
```

As you alredy see, there is an error in return, sadly I have to return only one element, like div or so. But when it comes to table jsx seems to feel pretty sick. How to get out of situation?

Here is a [question about multiple tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table/3076790), but.. "how can we put a tbody into another tbody then?"

Or should I first populate array of "rows" in js, and then render them in a single return (in a second component), eg:

```
class TreeView render() {
   rows=[];
   for(node of allNodes)
      rows.push(<TreeNode node={node}>);
   return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          { rows }
...
```

What is a typical common practice, to go with?

Answer (score 1):

hi why can't you wrap the two elements in a React.Fragment?? like this

```
class TreeNode extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let nestedLevel = this.props.level || 0;
        let childNodes = this.props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
            return <TreeNode key={index} node={node} level={nestedLevel+1} />
        });
        let identationMargin={margin: (nestedLevel*16)+"px"};
        return (
            <React.Fragment> 
                <tr className="treeview-row">
                    <td><span style={identationMargin} />User {this.props.node.name}</td>
                </tr>
                {childNodes}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it allowable to use it like so? I thought I only may use <tr> inside table or tbody..

Comment: my bad, i forgot the react.fragment  check this page https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: yep, i love you. div seems to break columns totally =( Just one minor notice is **F** for `React.Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure HTML/CSS solution.

Whenever you are building a table out of a tree, use `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags or their CSS equivalents `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` and apply `display:contents` to the elements that you intreleave with the table to preserve your tree structure without destroying the table layout.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikhailian/sf3xbuez/64/) for the working example.