# Why can't I get to table body element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a simple table, and this table contains thead, tbody and tfoot sections.  In JavaScript, I want to be able to access each of these parts to set some attributes.

I try to get the the parts with `table.tHead`, `table.tBody` and `table.tFoot` respectively.

**This works for tHead and tFoot just fine, but tBody always returns undefined.**

Looking inside the table object with the browser debugger, I can see that table.childNoes and table.children shows all the table parts, including tbody.

Strangely, if I access the tbody section using its ID with **document.getElementById("TB") it works just fine**.

Can anyone explain this to me?  Here's the source HTML with JavaScript:

```js
let table1 = document.getElementById("TBL1");

if (typeof(table1) != "undefined") {
  console.log(" - table element 'TBL1' acquired");

  let thead = table1.tHead;
  if (typeof(thead) != "undefined") {
    console.log(" - table element table1.tHead acquired,");
    thead.style.color = "#ffff50";
    console.log("   thead color changed to " + thead.style.color);
  } else
    console.log(" OOPS - could not access table table1.tHead");


  let tbody = table1.tBody;
  if (typeof(tbody) != "undefined") {
    console.log(" - table element table1.tBody acquired,");
    tbody.style.color = "#504020";
    console.log("   tbody color changed to " + tbody.style.color);
  } else
    console.log(" OOPS - could not access table table1.tBody");

  let tfoot = table1.tFoot;
  if (typeof(tfoot) != "undefined") {
    console.log(" - table element table1.tFoot acquired,");
    tfoot.style.color = "#ffff50";
    console.log("   tfoot color changed to " + tfoot.style.color);
  } else
    console.log(" OOPS - could not access table table1.tFoot");
} else
  console.log("OOP - Couldn't acquire TBL1 table");

if (typeof(tbody) == "undefined") {
  tbody = document.getElementById("TB");
  if (typeof(tbody) != "undefined")
    console.log(" - table element table1.tBody acquired using getElementById('TB'),");
  tbody.style.color = "#504020";
  console.log("   tbody color changed to " + tbody.style.color);
}

console.log(" - Done with table element access test");
```

```css
thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #3f87a6;
  color: #ffff;
}

tbody {
  background-color: #64d0c0;
  color: #ffff;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script>
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#A0C0C0";
    console.log("Testing table element access -");
  </script>

  <div ID="DIV1">
    <table ID="TBL1" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px;">
      <caption>
        Council budget (in £) 2018
      </caption>

      <thead ID="TH">
        <tr ID="HROW">
          <td>Items</td>
          <td scope="col">Expenditure</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody ID="TB">
        <tr ID="BROW1">
          <td scope="row">Donuts</td>
          <td>3,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ID="BROW2">
          <td scope="row">Stationery</td>
          <td>18,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot ID="TF">
        <tr ID="FROW">
          <td scope="row">Totals</td>
          <td>21,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Protip: Use `const` for element values instead of `let`.

Comment: you are also missing something in the else `} else` actually your entire code is full of those weird else statements

Comment: Always check the docs. While you'll find that [`tHead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tHead) and [`tFoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tFoot) do exist, you'll notice that `tBody` does not. While looking around what other properties exist, however, you'll surely notice [`tBodies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies) then!

Comment: @ChrisG You're not obliged to have `{}` after an `if` statement, only the first next instruction will be subjet to the condition. It's the same for `else`, although I agree with you that's a unusual syntax we have here, it's valid

Comment: oh ok, never seen that syntax before

Comment: @ChrisG yeah me neither, usually without braces we put the instruction on the same line, it's clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `tBody` property on a HTMLTableElement. There can be *multiple* `tbody` elements within a single table, so there's a `tBodies` collection which returns a NodeList of them all.

In your example, as you know there is only a single `tbody` instance, you can access the 0th element by index:

```js
let table1 = document.getElementById("TBL1");

if (table1) {
  let thead = table1.tHead;
  if (thead) {
    thead.style.color = "#ffff50";
  }

  let tbody = table1.tBodies[0]; // Note the property name and index accessor here
  if (tbody) {
    tbody.style.color = "#504020";
  }

  let tfoot = table1.tFoot;
  if (tfoot) {
    tfoot.style.color = "#ffff50";
  }
}
```

```css
thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #3f87a6;
  color: #ffff;
}

tbody {
  background-color: #64d0c0;
  color: #ffff;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV1">
  <table id="TBL1" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px;">
    <caption>
      Council budget (in £) 2018
    </caption>
    <thead id="TH">
      <tr ID="HROW">
        <td>Items</td>
        <td scope="col">Expenditure</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="TB">
      <tr id="BROW1">
        <td scope="row">Donuts</td>
        <td>3,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="BROW2">
        <td scope="row">Stationery</td>
        <td>18,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot id="TF">
      <tr id="FROW">
        <td scope="row">Totals</td>
        <td>21,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

If there will ever be multiple `tbody` elements within your table, then you could implement a loop to iterate through them all.

Also, as an aside, note that it's generally good practice to keep attributes in your HTML in lowercase, and to avoid using inline `style` attributes. Use external stylesheets for all styling.

Answer (score 0):

[A table can have more than one body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table), and hence there is no single `tBody` property on an `HTMLTableElement` but instead [a `tBodies` array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies)<sup>1</sup>.

Therefore, you can access your table body using `table1.tBodies[0]` (returning the first and only body your table has).

It's always good to verify in the docs first whether some property you are trying to use even exists, and if it doesn't, what other properties there are which may do what you want!

---

<sub>**1:** Technically, it's a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and not an array.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, here is the same using querySelector

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#A0C0C0";
console.log("Testing table element access -");


let table1 = document.getElementById("TBL1");

if (typeof(table1) != "undefined") {
  console.log(" - table element 'TBL1' acquired");

  let thead = table1.querySelector('thead');
  if (typeof(thead) != "undefined") {
    console.log(" - table element table1 thead acquired,");
    thead.style.color = "#ffff50";
    console.log("   thead color changed to " + thead.style.color);
  } else
    console.log(" OOPS - could not access table table1.tHead");


  let tbody = table1.querySelector('tbody'); // first tbody. Use querySelectorAll to get more
  if (typeof(tbody) != "undefined") {
    console.log(" - table element table1 tbody #1 acquired,");
    tbody.style.color = "#504020";
    console.log("   tbody color changed to " + tbody.style.color);
  } else
    console.log(" OOPS - could not access table table1.tBody");

  let tfoot = table1.querySelector('tfoot');
  if (typeof(tfoot) != "undefined") {
    console.log(" - table element table1 tFoot acquired,");
    tfoot.style.color = "#ffff50";
    console.log("   tfoot color changed to " + tfoot.style.color);
  } else
    console.log(" OOPS - could not access table table1.tFoot");
} else
  console.log("OOP - Couldn't acquire TBL1 table");

tbody = document.getElementById("TB");
if (typeof(tbody) != "undefined")
  console.log(" - table element table1 tbody acquired using getElementById('TB'),");
tbody.style.color = "#504020";
console.log("   tbody color changed to " + tbody.style.color);


console.log(" - Done with table element access test");
```

```css
#TBL1 {margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 100px;}

thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #3f87a6;
  color: #ffff;
}

tbody {
  background-color: #64d0c0;
  color: #ffff;
}

caption {
  padding: 10px;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(120, 120, 120);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV1">
  <table id="TBL1">
    <caption>
      Council budget (in £) 2018
    </caption>

    <thead id="TH">
      <tr id="HROW">
        <td>Items</td>
        <td scope="col">Expenditure</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="TB">
      <tr id="BROW1">
        <td scope="row">Donuts</td>
        <td>3,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="BROW2">
        <td scope="row">Stationery</td>
        <td>18,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot id="TF">
      <tr id="FROW">
        <td scope="row">Totals</td>
        <td>21,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: `tbody = table1.querySelector('thead');` is it an error? shouldn't it be `querySelector('tbody')`?

Comment: Of course it was a paste error